# hooking up a portable generator to power my house

Tags: electrical

If I remove the electrical meter going to my house can I safely wire my 7000w/8750w max portable generator to the lugs that go only to the inside panel? If so what gauge wire should I use? (I know I will need a 3 wire cable 2 hot,1 ground)

Comment: Do you plan to completely and permanently disconnect the power company feed at the same time?

Comment: Most utilities get pretty angry if you mess with the meter, and like to charge fines if the meter seal is found to be broken.

Answer (score 6):

The only acceptable way to do this, I believe, is to install a "transfer switch" which guarantees that there is no way to ever have both line and generator connected at the same time. To protect power company staff and your neighbors, they do *not* want to trust you to pull the meter every time there is a power outage; someone might get lazy or forgetful some day.

Answer (score 3):

NO, you CANNOT simply remove the meter and wire to the meter box. This is incredibly dangerous and highly illegal.

Also, you are wrong about the cable. You need a neutral.

You MUST use a transfer switch or main breaker interlock to accomplish this.